# svn convenient manner to push local project to remote repo

Tags: svn

I created a demo project in local, now I want to push it to svn repo. Below is my operations to achieve this.

```
#push to remote repo
svn import  /home/foo/workspace/bar/spring-boot-demo \
https://svn.foo.com/svn/server/samples/spring-boot-demo/ \
-m "Initial import"
#found /home/foo/workspace/bar/spring-boot-demo does not to become a working copy automatically So I have to check it out 
svn checkout https://svn.foo.com/svn/server/samples/spring-boot-demo/

#then delete those files wanted to ignore
svn delete .classpath --keep-local
svn delete .settings --keep-local
svn delete .project --keep-local
svn delete target --keep-local

#then create .svnignore to include these ignored files and execute svn ignore
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
#commit again
svn commit
```

You can see it's very trouble, does exist some convenient manner to achieve this? In git you just need create a `.gitignore` then execute `git push`, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

By consulting a experience colleague, he told me could do as below:

```
#create a remote repo first
$ svn mkdir https://svn.foo.com/svn/server/samples/spring-boot-demo
$ svn co https://svn.foo.com/svn/server/samples/spring-boot-demo
Checked out revision 15667.
$ cd sprin-boot-demo
$ vim .svnignore
.classpath
.project
.settings
target
$ svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
property 'svn:ignore' set on '.'

$ cp -r ../demo/* spring-boot-demo/
$ svn add . --force
$ svn commit
```